# Use radio button in RecyclerView to allow only 1 selection

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, radio-button

I'm trying to use RadioButtons in a RecyclerView and I only want the user to be able to select one item. So if the user selects one the previously selected needs to be deselected. I am trying to handle this inside my onBindView method. This is the code in my adapter:

```
public class SelectCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Category2> categoryList;
    private Category2 category;
    private RadioButton radioButton;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count, nameCategory;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            nameCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_category);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            //overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        }
    }


    public SelectCategoryAdapter(Context mContext, List<Category2> categoryList, RadioButton radioButton) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        this.radioButton = radioButton;
    }

    @Override
    public SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.adapter_select_category, parent, false);

        return new SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SelectCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        category = categoryList.get(position);
        holder.nameCategory.setText(category.getName());
        if (category.getTasks() < 10){
            holder.count.setText(" " + Integer.toString(category.getTasks()) + " ");
        } else {
            holder.count.setText(Integer.toString(category.getTasks()));
        }

        holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.radioButton.setChecked(position == radioButton);
        holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                radioButton = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }

}
```

And this is the XML for the adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/add_category_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edittext_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#494949"
            android:textSize="@dimen/s_text_size"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="20"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ececec" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So, the first error is that I'm getting a "cannot resolve symbol radioButton" and I don't know why this is happening, it's working for the other 2 TextViews but for the radio button I get this error.

Comment: Why are you passing a `RadioButton` in to the constructor of your adapter? If each `MyViewHolder` is supposed to have a `RadioButton`, then `MyViewHolder` should have a reference to its' own `RadioButton` (just like how you have the title, count, and category `TextView`s). The reason you're getting the "cannot resolve symbol" is because you're trying to reference a field named radioButton on the `MyViewHolder` class, which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was looking through a lot of code and I got confused when mixing the code to adapt to my case.

Comment: Would you mind helping me to pass the content of the item's TextViews to my main activity now?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Model Class i.e. **Category2**
add a property

```
public class Category2{
    ....
    ...
    boolean isSelected  = false;
    int previousSelectedPosition = -1;
}
```

Inside **onBindViewHolder**

```
category = categoryList.get(position);

holder.radioButton.setChecked(category.getIsSelected());

holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                          if(previousSelectedPosition >= 0)
                                categoryList.get(previousSelectedPosition).setIsSelected(false);
                          previousSelectedPosition = position;
                          category.isSelected = !category.isSelected;
                          if(radioButton!=null)
                              radioButton.setChecked(false);
                          radioButton = holder.radioButton;
                          notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

            }
        });
```